# Static / Instance variables in ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm a Ruby newbie. Have a very basic question about static and instance variables.

```
class Test

  def self.init
    @@var_static = 1
    @member = 2
  end

  def self.print
    puts "@@var_static: #{@@var_static}"
    puts "@member: #{@member}"
  end

end

Test.init
Test.print
```

Why does the code above allow initialization of a member variable: @member, inside the static method: Test::init   ? My understanding was that usage of @member will throw an error because it is not tied to any instance of class Test. But no error is thrown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A class *is* an instance of an object though, and can have instance variables just like any other object:

```
>> Fixnum.class
=> Class
```

`Fixnum` the class is *an instance of* `Class`!

Comment: Which class is the @member variable tied to, and how can I find it?

Comment: I don't understand your question. When you define a class you are creating a single instance of `Class`. `Test` the class you just defined _is_ the instance which has `@member`.

Comment: Try: `Test.instance_variable_get('@member')`

Comment: it's all about the context your code is evaluated in. if you define a method with self.something then you are in the context of the class you are currently defining. so the "member" variable is a member of the class.

Comment: That is very much unlike Java. Trying to access a member variable from a static method will give a compile error. You have to have an instantiated object before you can get the instance variables.

Comment: @Chloe, the `Test` class here IS an instantiated object. It's an instance of `Class`.

Answer (score 1):

A good article explaining this is here: http://railstips.org/blog/archives/2006/11/18/class-and-instance-variables-in-ruby/